# Stop `(Parallel)Table` evaluation when wanted case is found

Tags: list-manipulation, procedural-programming, iterators

I have to go through a long list of evaluations, for which I suppose `Table` instead of `For` or `While` is the good way to go and actually I use `ParallelTable` to speed it up. But only the first one in the list satisfying a certain condition is needed. In order to save time, how to stop the evaluation once the first result is found?

I know `While` works. The concern is usually people suggest `Table` instead of `For` or `While` for speeding up.

A minimal example might be the following - trying to find the 100th prime number (`count==100` as the condition). Certainly, this specific example probably has other approaches. What I need is a general recipe described above.

```
count = 0;
Table[count += If[PrimeQ[i], 1, 0];, {i, 1000}];
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for `Throw[]`/`Catch[]`: `Module[{count = 0}, Catch[Table[count += If[PrimeQ[i], 1, 0]; If[count == 100, Throw[i]], {i, 1000}]]]`.

Comment: does it have to be ParallelTable? Can you do it with ParallelSubmit? Because with ParallelSubmit, together with WaitNext, you can stop the evaluation when the first result is finished. There is a guy who has this in a video at 1h 8m 8s: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9yuzQKsQfZA&t=1h8m8s

Comment: @J.M. It doesn't work for `ParallelTable`?

Comment: This sounds like the kind of thing [`ParallelTry`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelTry.html) was designed for

Comment: @LukasLang Exactly what I need. Thanks! You can make it an answer if you like.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't sure if `Throw[]`/`Catch[]` would work on parallel stuff (after all, I do not have access to a multicore machine), so I didn't write an answer. I guess Lukas's suggestion is the way to go.

Comment: @J.M.isinlimbo Although seemingly not working for parallel as far as I've tried, I do find `Throw[]/Catch[]` useful. Thanks for bringing it up.

Answer (score 1):

My first idea was a classical `While` loop along with `NextPrime`:

```
counter = 0;
p = Prime[1];
While[counter < 100,
 counter++;
 p = NextPrime[p];
 ];
p
```

But then it occurred to me that a simple `Nest` would also work:

```
Nest[NextPrime, 2, 100]
```